# Windows 11 laptop unexpected shutdown during sleep

Tags: crash, sleep, windows-11

I have a [Framework](https://frame.work) laptop running Windows 11.

Very often (but not every time) I put it to sleep, when I wake it up (by pressing the power button) it goes through the regular boot process and all my programs are closed.

In the System event log, I see:

| Level | Date and time | Source | Event ID | Task Category | Message |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Critical | 2/20/2023 11:24:49 AM | Kernel-Power | 41 | (63) | The system has rebooted without cleanly shutting down first. This error could be caused if the system stopped responding, crashed, or lost power unexpectedly. |
| Error | 2/20/2023 11:24:59 AM | EventLog | 6008 | None | The previous system shutdown at 4:20:36 AM on ‎2/‎20/‎2023 was unexpected. |
| Information | 2/20/2023 11:24:46 AM | Kernel-General | 12 | (1) | The operating system started at system time ‎2023‎-‎02‎-‎20T16:24:45.500000000Z. |

The last events before that in the System log are:

| Level | Date and time | Source | Event ID | Task Category | Message |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Information | 2/20/2023 4:23:02 AM | Netwtw12 | 7026 | None | The description for Event ID 7026 from source Netwtw12 cannot be found. Either the component that raises this event is not installed on your local computer or the installation is corrupted. You can install or repair the component on the local computer. If the event originated on another computer, the display information had to be saved with the event. The following information was included with the event: \Device\NDMP4 Intel(R) Wi-Fi 6E AX210 160MHz The message resource is present but the message was not found in the message table |
| Information | 2/20/2023 4:23:02 AM | Netwtw12 | 7025 | None | The description for Event ID 7025 from source Netwtw12 cannot be found. Either the component that raises this event is not installed on your local computer or the installation is corrupted. You can install or repair the component on the local computer. If the event originated on another computer, the display information had to be saved with the event. The following information was included with the event: \Device\NDMP4 Intel(R) Wi-Fi 6E AX210 160MHz The message resource is present but the message was not found in the message table |
| Information | 2/20/2023 4:22:14 AM | UserModePowerService | 12 | (10) | Process C:\Windows\System32\WUDFHost.exe (process ID:1568) reset policy scheme from {381b4222-f694-41f0-9685-ff5bb260df2e} to {381b4222-f694-41f0-9685-ff5bb260df2e} |
| Information | 2/20/2023 4:22:06 AM | UserModePowerService | 12 | (10) | Process C:\Windows\System32\WUDFHost.exe (process ID:1568) reset policy scheme from {381b4222-f694-41f0-9685-ff5bb260df2e} to {381b4222-f694-41f0-9685-ff5bb260df2e} |

I put the computer into sleep at 11:37, as shown in the System log:

| Level | Date and time | Source | Event ID | Task Category | Message |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Information | 2/19/2023 11:37:48 PM | Kernel-Power | 506 | (157) | The system is entering Modern Standby Reason: Power Button. |

Between the sleep at 11:37 and the end of the log at 4:23, there are hundreds of `Netwtw12` and `UserModePowerService` events very similar to the ones shown above.

How can I figure out why my computer is crashing during sleep and stop it from doing so?

Comment: With a wet finger in the wind I'd say the battery is too old and can't maintain it in suspend mode? Can you make it work for hours on battery only? If not, change the battery, it's maybe 50$?

Comment: @Sylvain The battery lasts for many hours of work. It's only 3 months old. When I turn it back on, the battery is still almost as full as I left it.

Comment: Try updating Power driver and BIOS and see if that helps.

Comment: @John I will try that right now.

Comment: Try *Settings > Update & Security > Troubleshoot > Additional troubleshooters*, find and click "Power" and then "Run the troubleshooter".

Comment: I have the very same issue with my Dell XPS. 1 month old, same issue, same behavior.

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is with the Intel AX210 Wi-Fi card. I'm on the same Wifi hardware and the "unexpected shutdown" happened when I entered my room from the school lab, or normally when the connection changede, as I found.
I left the lab and close the screen lid on 5:30, back home at 6:10 and opened the lid at 6:20, the shutdown happened at about 6:10 as the event indicted.

Comment: For what it's worth, I'm experiencing the exact same problem as the OP and I also have an Intel AX210 Wi-Fi card.

Comment: Intel has more recent drivers available on their website than what's in Windows Update, so I'm going to try that updated driver and see if it helps.

Comment: @EricLee Thanks, I'm already on the latest driver version from Intel website, but the problem's still here. My device (Lenovo laptop) comes with a pre-installed Realtek Wifi, but I replaced it with AX210. This problem also existed on Realtek, but not so frequent.

Comment: Same issue on Dell XPS 15 with Intel AX211, driver version 22.250.0.4. Will try to check if forcing hibernate instead of this bs "modern standby" would help.

Answer (score 0):

Since the error involves, "Device\NDMP4 Intel(R) Wi-Fi 6E AX210 160MHz," you might test changing *Power Options* to disable *wake timers*:

[image: Disable Wake Timers]

If that does not work, please add information by editing the question:

- Does the issue occur *only* on battery, or both while plugged in *and* on battery? (This might point to battery or Power Options issues).
- If it happens *only* on battery, *what is that charge state of the battery* immediately after the issue occurs?

Comment: Since I have the exact same issue, let me quickly answer this. (1) The wake timers here are *disabled*; it's actually the first thing i checked. Doesn't make a difference. Obviously it doesn't log these information things when there are no wake timers. (2) It happens both on battery and while plugged in. (3) The charge state of the battery is 100% as you can expect from a plugged in laptop. Immediately after the faulty reboot, I check eventvwr and find the very same log as above.